# Remotely edit a node.js project via WebStorm or VSCode that is hosted on WSL on Win 11 on a local network

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm developing a Node/Express project running on Ubuntu (WSL on Windows 11). I'd like to develop code on my laptop by remotely connecting to the Node project files using either WebStorm or VSCode.

I can ssh to the project by running:

```
ssh -t myuser@192.168.0.59 "wsl ~"
```

The `wsl` command nicely takes me to the root of my WSL installation but whenever I try to open a remote a location in VSCode, it displays the Windows (host) files (not the Ubuntu WSL filesystem).

I don't really want to go the vim route. Alternatively I'd use git to develop on my laptop and keep pushing the changes and pulling them from Ubuntu WSL but I don't believe that would be the most optimised flow.

Any idea of how I could do that?

Comment: Have you tried to start ssh daemon in WSL, so you ssh into WSL directly ?

Comment: @Philippe from what I was reading it looks like the WSL IP address is not exposed in the local network (I did an nmap scan which confirmed it)

Comment: Start your ssh@WSL on port `222`, then on Windows `netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=222 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=222 connectaddress=<WSL2_IP>`

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I did have to also add an inbound rule in Windows Defender Firewall to open port 222.